# BIRT is not finding .properties file containing localization at runtime (servlet)

Tags: java, servlets, birt

I have set up a BIRT (3.7) servlet as described here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Servlet_Example_(BIRT)_2.1.

In my report, I declared a property file resource and localized the report's labels. I created a default properties file which contains German and an 'en_GB' file containing English. In the Preview section this worked ok.

I deployed the web application to a Websphere server but here no localized texts are displayed when the report is rendered. Labels display their unlocalized texts and texts fetched by JavaScript are all 'null'.

I assume that the properties files are not being found.

Is there anything that I must do in the servlet to tell BIRT where to look for resources? e.g. adding context root to file names.

**Solution**

Thanks to @Dominique for the `setResourcePath` tip. I had to make a couple of other changes too.

- In the report resources I had declared 'WebContent/birt/propfile'. Changed this to simply 'propfile'.
- Had been passing the parameter '__locale' to the report. Defined a new parameter 'Locale' and used this instead.
- Added `beforeFactory` script: `reportContext.getDesignHandle().setStringProperty("locale", params["Locale"].value);`
- Added following to servlet: `birtReportEngine.getConfig().setResourcePath(request.getContextPath() + "/birt");`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the root path of your resources with the method *EngineConfig.setResourcePath*. In the example you linked you would need to invoke it before creating the engine:

```
config.setResourcePath("C:/path-to-my-resources-root");
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to share some findings which gave me quite a headaches.

As already mentioned above BIRT is apparently looking up the resource properties files with the designtime path, e.g. `<BIRT default resource path>/src/main/resources/messages` for a `messages_<locale>.properties` file (Maven structure).

But on runtime the properties files will be located in `WEB-INF/classes` for a web application.

To maintain design time localization I would not modify the path in the Resource properties files dialog as suggested above but provide an additional properties files entry on runtime.

So the complete solution would look like this:

- Set correct resource path

```java
EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
config.setResourcePath(context.getContextPath()+"WEB-INF/classes");
Platform.startup(config);
```

- Add path for properties file `messages_<locale>.properties`

```java
IReportRunnable report = engine.openReportDesign(reportDesign);
report.getDesignHandle().setProperty("includeResource", "messages");
```

- Set locale as desired

```java
task.setLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
```

Voilá, now you have a report design with localization working on designtime and runtime.

Hope this will help somebody.

Kind regards, Tilo

Comment: How to add Multiple properties file. Like you added messages_<locale>.properties.